# Abstracting the DataLayer (DAL) of a three-tier application

Tags: c#, architecture, factory-pattern, 3-tier

As continuation to my previous question, (see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737848/creating-a-loosely-coupled-scalable-software-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737848/creating-a-loosely-coupled-scalable-software-architecture))

Someone suggests to also Abstract the DAL like I abstracted the BLL from the Presentation Layer on my three tier project. Any suggestion on how to do this? Do I also need a factory between the BLL and the DAL? I need your input guys.. thanks.

Comment: I don't see why anybody is voting to close this, it seems like a perfectly good question.  He's asking for best practices and approaches for abstracting his data access.  That sounds like the kind of thing we want to foster.  Maybe re-word the question a little?

Comment: @David: his previous question is very detailed, with quite a bit of context. This continuation lacks that. The OP would get much better answers, IMO, if he edits his previous question with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting - I'd put abstraction between the BL and DAL way before I'd do that for the presentation layer.

The approach used in your other question seems reasonable - why don't you just reuse that?

- Yes you need a factory; but you can include this in a common class / assembly and have it just return a `object`, which you can then cast as it's returned - i.e: at the point in the BL where it's being called.
- (for completeness:) using `Activator.CreateInstance()` (as you've used in your other question) is the right way to go.
- For DAL I tend to use values stored in the config (as arguments to pass into the factory); it's not common to change the DAL implementation that often - so config works well for me.
- Observe the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (ISP) when designing the contractr / abstraction between the BL and DAL - if you do it right you'll be able to mix-and-match different physical DAL implementations at once.
- If you keep the DTO's and factory in a common assembly (possibly the same one) then it's easy to re-use them with the BL and various DAL implementation - **with the caveat** that you keep this common class as devoid of dependancies as possble.  If you do this you'll be able to add / udpate DAL implemenations without re-compiling and re-deploying the whole system.